# Fastest way to draw a bitmap?

Tags: c#, silverlight, performance, image, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a timelapse application and that requires drawing new frame every 30ms. Frames are stored in isolated storage (they are 640x480).

I tried loading them into MemoryStream first, and then convert to BitmapImage and assign as a Source for the Image control. But it's too long - it takes about 55ms. I measured and it's not  reading from isolated storage, it's actually loading image into Image control that take the longest.

Is there any way to draw images faster on windows phone with silverlight or should I consider doing so with XNA?

Comment: You should consider doing it in XNA instead. You'll never achieve the necessary level of performance otherwise.

Comment: Instead of loading the new image in every time, could you maybe overwrite the old image directly? Also performance is going to be tightly related to what model phone handset you're using.

Comment: What type of data is in the bitmaps? Are they like slides, or are you effectively streaming a really [really] inefficient movie?

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I'll give it a try then.

Comment: @Seph I tried that, had same performance issues.

Comment: @HiTechMagic Those are Jpegs, most likely difference between them wont be as huge so it's more like inefficient movie.

Comment: @Maxim: based on your response the most efficient means of streaming that type of data will be some form of video compression (which effectively just sends the changes each frame instead of the whole image). What have you tried?

Comment: Do you also target Mango-devices?

Comment: @HeinrichUlbricht Yes, it's mango only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28VS.95%29.aspx) class and the open source library [WritableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). The `Blit` method within `WriteableBitmapEx` will copy one bitmap into another. Not sure if it's fast enough for what you need, but it is very fast for what I'm doing with it.